# htaccess replace one parameter with other in url

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have installed WordPress in in subdirectory.

My url is domain/blog/post-title 
now I want  domain/pages/post-title

only want change blog with pages, how i can do it in htaccess so all my old url's can 301 redirect on new url?

Thanks